# Eight employees in a company

Tags: probability

There are 8 employees at a small company. The company have a Christmas tradition where each employee has to bring a small gift. The gifts are then put in a bag and later distributed by a random draw by each of the employees.

a) What is the probability that at least one of the employees don't not get their own gift?

**My answer**: Let $$A=\{\textrm{at least one of the employees don't get their own gift}\}.$$
The probability that one of them get a gift is $\frac{1}{8}$. So the probability that all of them get their gift is $\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{7}\cdots \frac{1}{1}$. Hence the answer is

$$P(A)=1-P(A^{c})=1-\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{7}\cdots \frac{1}{1}.$$

b) What is the probability that five of the employees get their own gift?

**My answer**: The probability is
$$\binom{8}{5}\left ( \frac{1}{8} \right )^{5}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{8} \right )^{3}.$$

Comment: You need to explain the rules of the game better. As stated it is not even clear how someone can _avoid_ drawing a gift. So based on those rules the answer to (a) should be $0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I've edited the post. I hope it is better this time. The rule is how it is stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) If it actually means "at least one employee does  not get his own gift" then you are correct.

b) You are wrong. The probability should be ${8\choose5}(2\cdot1)\over8!$ if it means exactly $5$ and ${8\choose5}3!\over8!$ if it mean at least $5$.

Edit
Actually Henno is right about the "at least 5" case, one need to add up exactly 5, exactly 6 and so on and my formula is incorrect

Comment: The number of derangements $N$ is essentially the number of permutations where $8-N$ elements are fixed at their original position.

Comment: If you are talking about part a), I believe it actually means at least one point is not mapped to itself, instead of no point is mapped to itself.

Comment: I understand the expressions you have put, $\binom{8}{5}$ and $8!$, but not this one $(2\cdot 1)$. Could you please explain the reason behind this idea? I saw in the another answer where it says about the partial derangements I am not familiar with this yet. Is it because that: if five gifts are taken, so there are 2 places between 3 gifts?

Comment: Essentially, we want the remaining three spots to be deranged. For the first spot we choose one number that's original not in the spot so there are two choices, we always have one of the remaining spot with only one choice left and the last remaining spot has only one choice left as well. For example we want deranged permutation of  $1,2,3$. The first number can be $2,3$, if we choose $2$, then the third number can have only one choice: $1$. The two only two permutations are $2,3,1$ and $3,1,2$

Answer (score 0):

$(a)$

I take it that for part $(a)$, "at least one of the employees **don't not** get their own gift" actually means "at least one of the employees **don't** get their own gift", and that gifts are drawn randomly, then your answer to part $(a)$ is correct.

$(b)$

I take it that by "five of the employees get their own gift", you mean **exactly** five.

This is related to [partial derangements](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialDerangement.html)

[A derangement is an arrangement when none of the objects are in their proper place.]

There are various formulas for derangements, of which a short one is $\lceil\dfrac{n!}{e}\rceil$

Denoting $n$ objects deranged by $D_n$,

Any $5$ of the $8$ may get their own gift, and the other $3$ must not.

$D_3 = \lceil\frac{3!}{e}\rceil = 2$

(actually for just $3$, you don't need formulas, you can just count $BCA$ and $CAB$)

Putting things together, $Pr =$ $\binom85\cdot2 \over 8!$

*PS*

If you meant at least 5, $\frac{\binom85\cdot D_3 + \binom86\cdot D_2 + 1}{8!}$

Note particularly, that after $6$ getting their own gift, you can only have all $8$ getting their own gift