# Eight employees in a company, part 2

Tags: probability

There are 8 employees at a small company. The company have a Christmas tradition where each employee has to bring a small gift. The gifts are then put in a bag and later distributed by a random draw by each of the employees.  (This is a continuation from the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503256/eight-employees-in-a-company/))

It turns out that the 8 employees are not that creative, and therefore only brought 3 different kind of gifts.

- 2 employees have brought a gift of type A
- 4 employees have brought a gift of type B
- 2 employees have brought a gift of type C

We imagine that the gifts are packed in a way that they are undistinguishable, so a person can't see if the gift e.g. is of type B.

a) What is the probability that all of them gets a gift of the same type they have given?

**My answer**: I am not sure about it.

\begin{align*}
P(\textrm{type A})&=\frac{2}{8}\frac{1}{7}\\
P(\textrm{type B})&=\frac{4}{6}\frac{3}{5}\frac{2}{4}\frac{1}{3}\\
P(\textrm{type C})&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1}
\end{align*}

b) What is the probability that none of them gets a gift of the same type they have given?

**My answer**: Again I am not sure about it.

\begin{align*}
P(\textrm{not type A})&=\frac{6}{8}\frac{5}{7}\\
P(\textrm{not type B})&=\frac{4}{6}\frac{3}{5}\frac{2}{4}\frac{1}{3}\\
P(\textrm{not type C})&=\frac{2}{2}\frac{1}{1}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

a) We are permuting three groups so it should be $2!2!4!\over8!$ and your answer is correct assuming the $1\over2$ in type $C$ is a typing mistake for $2\over2$.

b) You are not correct this time. In your reasoning, after you choose not type $A$, you cannot do anything but splitting into cases about not type $B$ because what you have given the two type $A$ guys might be type $B$ or not.

For the correct probability, first note that the original $A$ and $C$ guys must all get type $B$ so it is actually just $4!4!\over8!$

Comment: I do not really get about the case b). Is it that my $P(\textrm{not type B})$ is wrong, and two other probabilities are correct?

Comment: No, you are wrong by starting with $P(\textrm{not type A})$. If you do it this way, then you have to split into cases when you go to $B$ or $C$ cases. In general, you have to consider different cases and add them up for this type of questions but for this particular question there is a neat solution because $8$ is partitioned into exactly $4$ type $B$ and exactly $4$ non-type $B$.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer in the line of your thinking. For solving a) let's say that first the persons that brought in a gift of type $A$ will receive a gift, then the persons that brought in a gift of type $B$ and finally the persons that brought in a gift of type $C$. Then the probability that the first $6$ persons receive of gift of the type they brought in is: $$\frac28\frac17\frac46\frac35\frac24\frac13$$
If this happens then *all* employees receive a gift of the type they brought in.

For solving b) the same with this difference that first the persons that brought a gift of type $B$ will receive a gift. The probability that they will receive a gift not of type $B$ is:$$\frac48\frac37\frac26\frac15$$

If this happens then *all* employees receive a gift of not of the type they brought in.